# How do I trigger the action on this element on plus.google.com via a userscript using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, userscripts, google-plus

I'm using Google+ quite heavily and one thing I find myself doing extremely frequently is clicking the 'More' button in the left-hand sidebar to access my circles that are hidden from view. I'm trying to write a user script that will activate the "More" link for me on page load. This is the DOM structure of the sidebar upto the "More" element:

```
<div class="a-b-la-A">
<h2 class="a-za">Navigation</h2>
<a href="/welcome" target="_top" class="d-h a-b-h-Jb a-la-h a-la-aH ">Welcome</a>
<div class="a-la-Dd"></div>
<a href="/stream" target="_top" class="d-h a-b-h-Jb a-la-h a-la-aH  a-la-h-Pa">Stream</a>       
<div class="a-la-h-ga"><a href="/stream/circles/p5653c3hhy60aadf997" target="_top" class="d-h a-b-h-Jb a-la-h a-la-Rb-h a-b-la-Rb-h">Friends</a></div>
<span role="button" class="d-h a-b-la-gc-h a-la-h a-la-hA" tabindex="0">More<span class="a-b-la-bw a-la-tb-q">▾</span></span>
```

...and here's the snippet I'm working on:

```
$('div.a-b-la-A span').filter('[role="button"]:contains("More")').trigger('click');
```

I can select and manipulate the 'More' element just fine and [here's the bg-color set to yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp6Js.png) with:

```
$('div.a-b-la-A span').filter('[role="button"]:contains("More")').css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
```

...but I still can't activate the function tied to the element. Things I've tried:

1. tried using .click() instead of trigger('click')
2. tried to identify the function getting triggered on click, using Firebug and Event Spy with no success
3. tried .mousedown() and trigger('mousedown') instead of triggering the 'click' event

Any other ideas?

Comment: NB: `$('div.a-b-la-A span').filter('[role="button"]:contains("More")')` can be shorted to `$('div.a-b-la-A span[role="button"]:contains("More")')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use low-level code to Fire the JS link.   Something like this should work:

```
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
clickEvent.initEvent ("click", true, true);

var jNode       = $('div.a-b-la-A span').filter('[role="button"]:contains("More")');
if (jNode.length != 1)
    alert ('Oops! Found too many (or no) "More" links');

jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
```

Comment: Yep, you have the right idea. Had to make some small changes (like MouseEvents instead of HTMLEvents) to make it work, here's the snippet I'm using now: var moreLink= $('div.a-b-la-A span').filter('[role="button"]:contains("More")'); var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); clickEvent.initEvent( 'click', true, true ); moreLink[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent); Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Weird that you had to use `MouseEvents` instead of `HTMLEvents`.  Usually Firefox will work either way. Are you (also) using Chrome?